# POST operations with JSON data request and response - Retrofit vs Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2

I've previously used Volley, and its `JsonObject` and Request methods.

I want now to use Retrofit's `POST` operations with JSON data request and response, is this a better approach than Volley?

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tutorials on internet like this [Retrofit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Comment: Really appreciate that you tried to help. Try to add bit more explanation. One liners doesn't look too appealing.